# How to Restart a Service Remotely using Powershell on Server 2016

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I'm having an issue with the Print Spooler getting hung up on a Hyper-V server that im running and tickets get hung up...Im just trying to streamline this by figuring out how i can just run a powershell script without having to enter any credentials manually. I can get a powershell script to accomplish this but the only one that i have found implements the Get-Credentials and prompts to enter credentials  then i get put into a remote Powershell session on the server where i can restart the service from there.

Is there an easier way to accomplish what i am trying to do?

Comment: Will you be running this script using an account that's local admin on the target Hyper-V server?

Comment: Yes I will. i actually am just using the Administrator account to try and accomplish this.

Comment: If you launch PowerShell with a domain account that has local admin on the remote box, then you don't need to provide credentials again. Simply do `Restart-Service -Name spooler -ComputerName hyperv-server.domain.fqdn` or `Invoke-Command {Restart-Service -Name spooler} -ComputerName hyperv-server.domain.fqdn`, PowerShell will simply default to the callers network identity when no explicit credentials are passed

Comment: Using Invoke-Command {Restart-Service -Name spooler} -ComputerName hyperv-server.domain.fqdn  I get Access Denied.

Comment: I can use this and it works fine im just trying to avoid the whole popup box and having to enter in my credentials.                                                                             
New-Pssession -Name remote -computername server -credential (get-credential)
Enter-PsSession -Name Remote
$service = "Spooler"

Function GetService {
Get-service -name $service
}
Function RestartService {
Restart-Service -Name $Service
}
Function StopService {
Stop-Service -Name $Service -Force
} 
function StartService {
Start-Service -name $Service
}

Comment: Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64230781/edit), comments aren't well fit for code :) FWIW, you just need to remove `-credential (get-credential)` do avoid the prompt, but if you're getting access denied, then there's something else wrong. Are both servers joined to the same domain/forest?

Comment: If you get access denied then it means your account isn't allowed to perform that action. Are you sure you are logged on with a domain account that have the correct permission on the other system? The `Invoke-Command` do work provided you have the correct permission and no firewall settings is acting up...